# anchor tag all jump when returning to the home page because of slider

Tags: anchor

The anchor tags I have in the nav bar work fine on the home page, but if you click on one from another page, it will go to the correct spot only to jump down when the slider loads.

Is there some kind of fix for this problem?

This is the site:
http://www.nfgraphicdesign.ca/wpdemo

if you navigate from 
http://www.nfgraphicdesign.ca/wpdemo/buyers/ and current listings you will see what I mean.

Thanks a lot for any help with this.